# How to create spatially filtered versions in ArcSDE 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I am using ArcSDE 10.1 and Oracle 11g,

I have a SDE user (parent), and two more users (ex: user1,user2) in my oracle database with required SDE permissions.
In my SDE db, i have a polygon FeatureClass (Ex: world) with a field called region (attribute values are North and South) and it is registered as versioned under sde.default.

And now i would like create, two child versions for sde.default (Ex: version1,version2) for user1 and user2 respectively and i would like to allow user1(version1) to view/edit the data related to a particular region(Ex:North), similarly for the user2(version2) to view/edit data related to the region south.

Is it possible to apply the above filter while creating versions in ArcSDE database?

Comment: The "too short" answer is "No." If you change the question to reflect either some basic research into the versioned editing optimistic locking model or more detail on your end goal (perhaps in the context of child-parent replication), you might get a more useful answer than a description of versioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow users to view/edit data based on geographical regions, [replication](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000v4000000) is there for you.
You can replicate your data and assign each dataset to individual user. If replication is too complex for your scenario (@vince's comment), you can use a Definition Query with spatial predicates (e.g. `st_intersect`) to limit  users from viewing and editing your data.

Comment: You really ought to mention that three database instances would be necessary for this solution. I think "you *could*" would be more appropriate than *should*, because this is really a far too complicated solution to the stated problem (two users and one table).